# Angularjs 1.5 - Component Communication using service - Async variable manipulation?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, components, angular-services

I am very new to this Angular component communication. I am using Angular 1.5.X version and I am using factory to share data between components. I am facing one issue where Async value of Service Variable refreshes after certain time.

I understand one solution is to set watcher on non scope variable but I think I am missing something important here. Can you guys please share views?

This is Service.js code

```
Service.$inject = ['$http','$q'];

function Service($http,$q) {

  this.$http = $http;
  this.$q = $q;

};

Service.prototype.getTileCount = 0;

Service.prototype.getTileData = function(Url){

    var deferred = this.$q.defer();

    this.$http.get(Url)
        .success(function(response){
            Service.prototype.getTileCount = response.data.length;
            console.log('data length :', Service.prototype.getTileCount);
        deferred.resolve(response);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

This is component 1 controller code

```
function Component1Controller(Service) {

    this.tileData ={};
    var self = this;

    var promise = Service.getTileData(this.sourceUrl);

      promise.then(function(data) {

        self.tileData = data;
        Service.getTileCount = data.length;
        console.log('This is tileData : '+ Service.getTileCount);
      });

    };
```

This is component 2 controller code

```
function Component2Controller(Service) {

  var self = this;

  console.log(Service.getTileCount);
// getting getTileCount = 0; After setting timeout function of 5 second I am able to get getTileCount value

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that `Service.getTileCount` is updated asynchronously, that's why it's `0` at first and then at some point it changes. I would recommend you to simplify your service and always work with `getTileData` method, which would be a single source of data. The implementation would also become simpler:

```
function Service($http, $q) {
  this._tileData = null;
  this.$http = $http;
  this.$q = $q;
}

Service.prototype.getTileData = function(Url) {

  if (!this._tileData) {
    this._tileData = this.$http.get(Url).then(function(response) {
      return response.data;
    }.bind(this));
  }

  return this._tileData;
};
```

Note, how it caches tiles response in "private" `_tileData` property. Now you can always rely on `getTileData` method which will return data no matter when you call it:

```
function Component1Controller(Service) {

  this.tileData = {};
  var self = this;

  Service.getTileData(this.sourceUrl).then(function(data) {
    self.tileData = data;
    console.log('This is tileData:', self.tileData.length);
  });
};

function Component2Controller(Service) {
  var self = this;
  Service.getTileData(this.sourceUrl).then(function(data) {
    console.log('tile count', data.length);
  });
};
```

In this case `Service.getTileCount` is not needed anymore.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/3zE6VL4emXaLRx2nCRih?p=info

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried the same approach but from both the component service call I am getting this._tileData of service as null. so I think we are not able to store this._tileData object value so on next call we are getting again null. so basically we are hitting $http service twice which is not a good solution.

Comment: Of course no, the point of my solution is that you never make more then one request (service caches data) and that no matter from which component you request `getTileData` you will always get data in predictable way.

Comment: I however found an error in my code, check out updated version that would be better for your situation.

Comment: Thanks! that works for me :) btw one question... if in case I have two componets A & B and I need to pass object between two what should be the best way apart from service/factory. I understand inherited scope & broadcast/emit is not a good practice. I tried parent child component relationship but felt difficult to implement. Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: The best way to setup such a communication is to use parent component controller and use bindings to bas the same object to every component that needs it. `<one data="$ctrl.data"></one><two data="$ctrl.data"></two>`.

Comment: That's interesting! if you don't mind can you please share some online tutorial! I hope I am not bothering you! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Here is an article I put together about it: http://dfsq.info/site/read/angular-components-communication

Comment: Thanks for the help :)